# Observing relativistic motion from afar

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

If I were to look at a clock from a very far distance ( let's say 10 light-years away ), and the clock starts to move on a direction perpendicular to my line of sight, with a speed approaching c (e.g. 0.999c), will I see the clock ticking at a different rate (slower/faster) than it was before starting to move?

The large distance and it being perpendicular to the direction of movement are important because it makes the distance between the observation point and the moving clock constant (it would take a lot of time before the angle changes significantly).

Comment: Is the clock ticking slower in your frame of reference? No. But do you *see* the clock ticking at a different rate? Yes. Which case are you referring to?

Comment: @DanDan0101 the question refers specifically to what the observer would "see" in such a setup

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would see the clock running slowly- the result of the transverse relativistic Doppler effect. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect#Transverse_Doppler_effect

Comment: That's a pretty long article covering multiple cases. However, the question seems to match the part talking about the "Point of null frequency shift" which suggests the clock would appear as running at normal speed. Did I get that wrong?